# Cornerstone cannot connect to my svn server

Tags: mac, svn

It always return:

```
Description : Unable to connect to the repository due to an authentication or authorization failure.  Suggestion : Make sure that the account information you have specified is correct and that you are authorized to access the repository using this account.   Technical Information
=====================

      Error : V4Error   Exception : ZSVNAuthorizationException

Causal Information
==================

Description : Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://url_to_project'
     Status : 170001

Description : OPTIONS of 'http://url_to_project': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://baseurl)
     Status : 170001
```

But I can use the same account and password to login the server with Versions App, command line or Web Browser. So the account and password cannot be wrong. Now what can I do to resolve the problem?